# Copyright charset error on emails

Tags: email, zurb-foundation, html-email, haml, inky

I am trying to insert a copyright character in an email, but I always get charset issues.

```
&copy;
```

Result: ÃÂÃÂ©

```
&#169;
```

Result: ÃÂÃÂ©

```
&#9426;
```

Result: ÃÂ¢ÃÂÃÂ

```
&#9400;
```

Result: ÃÂ¢ÃÂÃÂ

My stack is Foundation For Emails, Inky, Haml and I've set charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing the charset issue? In the delivered email? If so, what email browser are you using?

It's possible that you have an invalid character somewhere else in your code. Some email browsers will see a character with a different encoding than UTF-8, decide "Oh, I guess we're using ISO-8859 now", and then switch to that encoding for the rest of the email.